# dispatch_semaphore_wait cannot wake in a new window

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.progressWindowController = [[ProgressWindowController alloc]init];
    _sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
}
- (IBAction)signalInMain:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(_sem);
    [self.progressWindowController.window close];

}
- (IBAction)wait:(id)sender
{
    //[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f target:self selector:@selector(closeWin:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void){


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self showProgressWindow];

        });
        NSLog(@"WAIT");
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(_sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        NSLog(@"done");
        [self.progressWindowController.window close];

    });
}

- (void)showProgressWindow
{

//    [self.window beginSheet:self.progressWindowController.window completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse returnCode) {
//
//    }];
    [self.progressWindowController showWindow:self];
}

- (IBAction)signalInNew:(id)sender
{
    //[self.progressWindowController.window close];
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(_sem);
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    //[self waitFromUI];
}
```

The work flow is:
In the main window there are two buttons: wait and signal1.Click wait button will call `dispatch_semaphore_wait` and show a new window, click signal1 button will call `dispatch_semaphore_signal`.  In the new window there is another button: signal2, click signal2 button will call `dispatch_semaphore_signal`.

The issue is:
 Click signal1 can make everything work well. But click signal2 button will not wake up the main window, dispatch_semaphore_wait will not be ended.
Anybody knows why this happen?

Comment: The fact that you are using `dispatch_semaphore_wait` in this situation is a likely bad smell. You should not be doing _any_ "waiting" in a Cocoa application. Why not ask about the _real_ problem you are trying to solve — the one that you are solving (wrongly) by resorting to `dispatch_semaphore_wait` in the first place?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but after you log "done", you are calling `[self.progressWindowController.window close]` on a background queue. You should do all UI stuff on the main queue, so you should dispatch that `close` back to the main thread, just like you did for showing the window.

Comment: I agree with matt, that you really should excise this semaphore stuff from your code. It's unnecessary and inadvisable. Setting that aside for a second, though, I'm having a hard time understanding what the flow is here. You talk about having two different `signal` buttons, but I see only one `IBAction` that does a signal. This is a little confusing...

Comment: Even you are correct about the usage in that code, I assume that this is a boiled-down example. However, let it be a code smell. It should work.

Comment: @matt, i want to do something in background thread and wait for a response from UI operation in main thread. So do you have any better solution here

Comment: @Rob, there are two action in my code, signalInMain and signalInNew

Comment: @jimwan - Yeah, you've got two signal routines, but only one wait routine. So, are you saying that `wait` was called, you didn't click on signal1 but did click on signal2, and the `dispatch_semaphore_wait` did not catch the signal?

Comment: @Rob, yes. What should i do?

Comment: @jimwan - There's nothing particularly tricky with semaphores, so the problem must rest elsewhere. For example, I'd suggest doing some logging to ensure you're dealing with the same semaphore on both threads: Add a logging of the semaphore where you wait and again in both places you signal and make sure you've got the same instance (i.e. exact same memory address). Also make sure that every wait is offset by precisely one signal. And make sure you're diagnosing this on the basis of log statements or breakpoints and not the appearance and disappearance of your progress view.